# how to prompt the user before form load event fires in windows forms application using c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-mobile

i want to prompt the user to enter his number to get the details from database before the form Load event fire in windows forms application using c#?

can anyone please tell me how to implement this?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Put it into the Main method of Program.cs.

You can show a winform or dialog in the Main method before you run your main application.  This allows the user to enter some data and you can then act on that before running your main form.

I have an application that can start in one of two ways.  I display a selector window from Main.  The user selects from the options and I collect that when the selector form closes.

I then start my main form taking account of that. This would also allow you to start different forms depending on the user input if you wish

Comment: Hi, I am using the visual basic InputBox for prompting the user in Program.cs before application.run method  but, it is occupying the total form size. How can place this at a particular place with particular size?

Answer (score 0):

Write your code in program.cs or in constructor of form

Comment: Hi I am using Visual Basic InputBox for prompting the user in program.cs before application.start method but it is occupying the total form size , how can i place this at a particular place and size?

Comment: use that VB form's top and left properties for where it has to be placed
use height and width property for size